# Ambiguous use of intValue Swift3

Tags: migration, swift3, swift2

I have been trying to convert existing swift2.3 to swift3. I got ***Ambiguous use on intValue error*** at the following code.

**jobPackageVersion.intJobPackageId =    (JobPackageVersionDictionary["intJobPackageId"]! as AnyObject).intValue as   NSNumber**

Here is the full code

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "tblJobPackageVersion", withExtension: "csv") {
  do {
    let strData = try String(contentsOf: url)
    let csv = CSwiftV(String: strData)

    if csv.keyedRows != nil {
      for dictionary in csv.keyedRows! {  // [Dictionary<String, String>]
        let JobPackageVersionDictionary = dictionary as NSDictionary  // Cast to NSDictionary
        let JobPackageVersionEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "JobPackageVersion", in: context)
        let jobPackageVersion = JobPackageVersion(entity: JobPackageVersionEntity!, insertInto: context)

        // Set object attributes
        jobPackageVersion.intJobPackageId = (JobPackageVersionDictionary["intJobPackageId"]! as AnyObject).intValue as NSNumber
        jobPackageVersion.intJobPackageVersionId = (JobPackageVersionDictionary["intJobPackageVersionId"]! as AnyObject).intValue as NSNumber 
        jobPackageVersion.intStatus = (JobPackageVersionDictionary["intStatus"]! as AnyObject).intValue as NSNumber
        jobPackageVersion.intVersion = (JobPackageVersionDictionary["intVersion"]! as AnyObject).intValue as NSNumber

        do { // Save object to database and clean up memory
          try context.save()
          context.refresh(jobPackageVersion, mergeChanges: false)
        } catch let error as NSError { Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function) JobPackageVersion Saving Error: \(error.userInfo)") }
      } // for-loop

      Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function): Loaded \(csv.keyedRows!.count) tblJobPackageVersion records.")
    } else { Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function) CSV Parser Warning: no CSV data was parsed in tblJobPackageVersion.csv!") }
  } catch { Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function) Error reading contents of tblJobPackageVersion.csv.") }
} else { Logger.sharedInstance.logMessage("\(#function) Error locating URL for resource tblJobPackageVersion.csv") }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call `intValue` on an object of type `AnyObject`. As the error states, this is too ambiguous because both `NSNumber` and `NSString` have `intValue` properties. Xcode doesn't know which `intValue` to use, because both `NSNumber` and `NSString` fall under the `AnyObject` umbrella. Since Xcode is confused, you need to be more specific about what type your object is. Try something like this:

```
jobPackageVersion.intJobPackageId = (JobPackageVersionDictionary["intJobPackageId"]! as NSNumber).intValue
```

**Note 1:** You're probably going to get the same error with the other objects you call `intValue` on, but you can fix them accordingly.

**Note 2:** Be extremely careful about force unwrapping your objects using `!`. If the dictionary you're using ever returns nil your program will crash. Instead I would safely unwrap them using either an `if let` or `guard` statement depending on your use case. Something like this may work a little better:

```
guard let intJobPackageId = JobPackageVersionDictionary["intJobPackageId"] as? NSNumber,
      let intJobPackageVersionId = JobPackageVersionDictionary["intJobPackageVersionId"] as? NSNumber,
      let intStatus = JobPackageVersionDictionary["intStatus"] as? NSNumber,
      let intVersion = JobPackageVersionDictionary["intVersion"] as? NSNumber
else {
    print("one of the dictionary values is nil")
    return
}

jobPackageVersion.intJobPackageId = intJobPackageId.intValue
jobPackageVersion.intJobPackageVersionId = intJobPackageVersionId.intValue
jobPackageVersion.intStatus = intStatus.intValue
jobPackageVersion.intVersion = intVersion.intValue
```

This may not be exactly what you want, but it should give you an idea on how to safely unwrap your objects so your app doesn't crash. You can play around with it and decide what's best for you.